# Aligning Figure Titles and Page Numbers

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

As a new user of LaTeX, I've encountered a challenge with aligning the titles of figures and their corresponding page numbers. I would greatly appreciate some guidance from the LaTeX community on how to address this issue.
I use this code :

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed,titletoc,lmodern}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{%
        \hspace{6em}%
        {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}%
        \hspace{1em}%
    }%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt\relax
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
{\parbox{4.5em}{%
        \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
    \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar
    \textsc{\small\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}

{}{\endleftbar}



\titlecontents{section}
[8.4em]
{\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
{\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
[8.4em]
{\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}  
{\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}




\titlecontents{figure}
[0em]{\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}}
{\parbox{4.5em}{%
        \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
    \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar
    \textsc{\small Figure~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
{}{\endleftbar}



\titlecontents{table}
[0em]{\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}}
{\parbox{4.5em}{%
        \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
    \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar
    \textsc{\small Table~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
{}{\endleftbar}


\newcommand*\updatemylof{%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\section*{Chapter~\thechapter}}%
}
```

the result :

[image]

I would like to modify this code to ensure that the title of the figure and the page number are displayed on the same line,

Comment: \vspace will always cause a line break.  Use \raisebox instead.  Or just `\parbox[b]{...}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo the same problem with \raisebox .

Comment: Do you **have** to use titletoc and framed?

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes i use titletoc and framed